# JQuery style display value

Tags: jquery, css

How can I check the display value of an element

```
<tr id="pDetails" style="display:none">
```

`$("tr[id='pDetails']").attr("style")` gives me `'display:none'`

I want to write a jquery script that will return me only the value of display which is 'none'

Is that possible?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Just call [css](http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/css#name) with one argument

```
  $('#idDetails').css('display');
```

If I understand your question.  Otherwise, you want cletus' answer.

Comment: I think this answer can be wrong. Excuse me if I'm wrong, but I think `.css()` returns the computed style, which can include inherited styles. I think the OP  wants to get the inline style. That's the hard thing to do!

Answer (score 19):

Well, for one thing your epression can be simplified:

```
$("#pDetails").attr("style")
```

since there should only be one element for any given ID and the ID selector will be **much** faster than the attribute id selector you're using.

If you just want to return the display value or something, use css():

```
$("#pDetails").css("display")
```

If you want to search for elements that have display none, that's a lot harder to do reliably. This is a rough example that won't be 100%:

```
$("[style*='display: none']")
```

but if you just want to find things that are hidden, use this:

```
$(":hidden")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the display value, https://stackoverflow.com/a/1189281/5622596 already posted the answer.

However if instead of checking whether an element has a style of `style="display:none"` you want to know if that element is visible. Then use `.is(":visible")`

For example: 
`$('#idDetails').is(":visible");`

This will be `true` if it is visible & `false` if it is not.

Answer (score -1):

This will return what you asked, but I wouldnt recommend using css like this. Use external CSS instead of inline css.

```
$("tr[id='pDetails']").attr("style").split(':')[1];
```

Comment: This is bad because it doesn't generalize when the style attribute has more than just display:blah (anything, like width:100, would get mixed into the split(':')[1])